# Import image using feeds and image path?

Tags: 7, media, feeds

With Drupal 7, I am using feeds to import an XML file. That file has a relative image path I can import, but not the image itself.

How can I save the image to the node itself instead of saving the image path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should work automatically, but you need to use a valid path schema, for example: `public://images/myimage.jpg`. Otherwise [Feeds needs to know the absolute path to these images](https://www.drupal.org/node/1041030#comment-9564683). If needed, use Feeds Tamper to correct image paths.